# When and where can I first sell my non-magical jewelry?

Tags: planescape-torment

I've collected quite a bit of non-magical jewelry in the hive and mortuary of Planescape Torment (I'm about half-way through the second "chapter").

I've just been dumping it in the empty tomb next to Angyar's home to make room in my inventory. Will I ever be able to sell it? Where and when? Also, is it safe in the tomb?

Lastly, is it worth it to lug copper and bronze jewelry around (or any non-magical jewelry, for that matter)?

Comment: I'm sure you can sell them at the second market (the one with the lovestory between the guard and the merchant), I'm not sure you can sell them at the first market, but I wouldn't think so). But yeah, you can sell them.

Comment: Upvote because this game is awesome

Comment: @DavidYell That's not really what upvotes are supposed to be for.

Comment: @PanicBomb I like to live dangerously, by upvoting things I like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yay! I’ve sold my hoarded jewelry, and I think I have had access to this place from the moment I got out of the mortuary. Mebbeth, the midwife in Ragpicker’s Square (her hut is just south of central of that section) sells magic and healing items, heals characters, identifies items, she’ll buy all of the jewelry you’ve got (for surprisingly good prices), and you can rest there for free. Even bronze rings (which collect like dust) go for 40 coppers.
So far I haven’t lost anything I’ve stashed in the empty tomb (I’ll update this answer if I ever do).